# Study if $f$ is differentiable in its domain

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Study if $f$ is differentiable in its domain, where $f(x) = \sqrt{x} -x$

I tried to have the derivative by the definition but I'm going nowhere with this.

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h} -(x+h) - (\sqrt{x}-x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h} -h - \sqrt{x}}{h}$$

And now I don't know what to do. I tried to multiply by the conjugate but didn't work.

Comment: What was this conjugate that you multiplied? Did you try taking the $-\frac{h}{h}$ out of the limit first?

Answer (score 1):

With your method, you write $\sqrt{x+h}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x}}$ and use the expansion of $(1+a)^{1/2}=1+\frac{a}{2}+\text{o}(a)$ which is valid when $a \to 0$.
Another approach can be the following: $\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain except for $x=0$ and $-x$ is differentiable everywhere, so the difference $\sqrt{x}-x$ is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x+h} -h - \sqrt{x}}{h}
=
\frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} -1 = \frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})}-1
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}-1.
$$
Now, if $x\neq 0$, you can take the limit and you get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-1$. But if $x=0$, we get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}-1 \to_{h \to 0} + \infty
$$
so the limit isn't finite.